# Deriving a equation in "Data re-uploading for a universal quantum classifier" paper: U(phi1,phi2,phi3) U(x1,x2,x3) = U(theta + w *x)

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, pennylane

In "Data re-uploading for a universal quantum classifier" paper the U(phi1,phi2,phi3) U(x1,x2,x3) is derived as U(theta + w *x) in compact state.
How to derive the above equation ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.